# Dojo/Dijit TitlePane

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

How do you make a titlePane's height dynamic so that if content is added to the pane after the page has loaded the TitlePane will expand?

Comment: Hmm, I thought that was the default behaviour. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RxybY/

Comment: no. I have ContentPane that I populate when the page loads and it pushes content below it out of view

Comment: Just tried the `fiddle`. Must be something I'm doing!?!

Comment: Hmm, weird. Can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle, or otherwise share some code?

Comment: Pritty hard since all of my stuff is declaritave. Jsfiddle doesn't like `<div dojoType="dijit.TitlePane" ...`. I'm doing it all declaritave because the page is dynamically loaded and programmatic doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: in jsfiddle on the left hand input "Library tag attributes" add `djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"`

Comment: Aye, jsfiddle is your friend :-) http://jsfiddle.net/B6fWX/

Comment: Please see the following: http://www.client-ms.com/test/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the rich content editor being an iframe that is loaded asynchronously confuses the initial layout.

As @missingno mentioned, the resize function is what you want to look at.

If you execute the following function on [your page](http://www.client-ms.com/test/), you can see that it does correctly resize everything:

```
//iterate through all widgets
dijit.registry.forEach(function(widget){
    //if widget has a resize function, call it
    if(widget.resize){
        widget.resize()
    }
});
```

The above function iterates through all widgets and resizes all of them.  This is probably unneccessary.  I think you would only need to call it on each of your layout-related widgets, after the dijit.Editor is initialized.

The easiest way to do this on the actual page would probably to add it to your addOnLoad function.  For exampe:

```
    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        dijit.byId("ContentLetterTemplate").set("href","index2.html");
        //perform resize on widgets after they are created and parsed.
        dijit.registry.forEach(function(widget){
              //if widget has a resize function, call it
              if(widget.resize){
                  widget.resize()
              }
        });
    });
```

EDIT:  Another possible fix to the problem is setting the `doLayout` property on your Content Panes to false.  By default all ContentPane's (including subclasses such as TitlePane and dojox.layout.ContentPane) have this property set to true.  This means that the size of the ContentPane is predetermined and static.  By setting the `doLayout` property to false, the size of the ContentPanes will grow organically as the content becomes larger or smaller.

Comment: you right! I cut and paste it in and it works on the page. Then I tried it on my local and it didn't :( So I have carbon copied from my local to the page and it doesn't (check out the resize button)

Comment: Have you tried adding the resize functionality to the addOnLoad method? (see edit)

Comment: I can only use the addOnLoad function in the main page because it doesn't seem work in pages inside panes. I have tried a number of things on the page, and currently now its crashing (to much recursion). I only need really to resize `LetterTemplateTitlePane` and `ContentLetterTemplate`. When the page loads please select `Invoice Letter` from the first pulldown, it is only after this action is performed that the TitlePane need to be resized

Comment: in that case, you can use `dojo.connect` to connect to the Invoice Letter dropdown's `onChange` event to call the resize after you've displayed the `letterVariablesContainer` ContentPane

Comment: Can't do that because `onChange` replaces the page that the onChange event is in (if you see what I mean)

Comment: I think it's because the ContentPane that the TitlePane is in is not re-sizing

Comment: how about you tell me to put `doLayout="false"` on the TitlePane and I'll give you 50 points

Answer (score 2):

Layout widgets have a [`.resize()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/TitlePane#resize) method that you can call to trigger a recalculation. Most of the time you don't need to call it yourself (as shown in the examples in the comments) but in some situations you have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

I've made an example how to load data after the pane is open and build content of pane.

What bothers me is after creating grid, I have to first put it into DOM, and after that into title pane, otherwise title pane won't get proper height. There should be cleaner way to do this.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/keemor/T46tt/2/

```
dojo.require("dijit.TitlePane");
dojo.require("dojo.store.Memory");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ObjectStore");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.ready(function() {
    var pane = new dijit.TitlePane({
        title: 'Dynamic title pane',
        open: false,
        toggle: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.inherited('toggle', arguments);
            self._setContent(self.onDownloadStart(), true);
            if (!self.open) {
                return;
            }
            var xhr = dojo.xhrGet({
                url: '/echo/json/',
                load: function(r) {
                    var someData = [{
                        id: 1,
                        name: "One"},
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "Two"}];

                    var store = dojo.data.ObjectStore({
                        objectStore: new dojo.store.Memory({
                            data: someData
                        })
                    });
                    var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                        store: store,
                        structure: [{
                            name: "Name",
                            field: "name",
                            width: "200px"}],
                        autoHeight: true
                    });
                    //After inserting grid anywhere on page it gets height
                    //Without this line title pane doesn't resize after inserting grid                                                            
                    dojo.place(grid.domNode, dojo.body());
                    grid.startup();
                    self.set('content', grid.domNode);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    dojo.place(pane.domNode, dojo.body());
    pane.toggle();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to move `innerWidget.startup()` into the after advice to `"toggle"`.

```
titlePane.aspect = aspect.after(titlePane, 'toggle', function () {
    if (titlePane.open) {
        titlePane.grid.startup();
        titlePane.aspect.remove();
    }
});
```

See the [dojo/aspect reference documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html) for more information.